# How can I get this code working for all Buttons?

Tags: javascript

I try to build a landing page, where a box with a form pops up when the user clicks on contact.

I've added a modal script which works great, but only for one button. I added the id or class for all buttons but it's just not working.

```
<button class="trigger">Click here to trigger the modal!</button>
<div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close-button">×</span>
        <h1>Hello, I am a modal!</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
var modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
var trigger = document.querySelector(".trigger");
var closeButton = document.querySelector(".close-button");

function toggleModal() {
    modal.classList.toggle("show-modal");
}

function windowOnClick(event) {
    if (event.target === modal) {
        toggleModal();
    }
}

trigger.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
closeButton.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
window.addEventListener("click", windowOnClick);
```

I would like to be able to add the '.trigger' to any button or a-tag and have it working.

Comment: Can you please show us your html too.

Comment: here you go ...

Comment: It's global @Roy - that's not required.

Comment: @Roy `var modal` outside of all functions - it's global.

Comment: @JackBashford my bad, sorry.

Comment: can anyone show me an example?

Comment: is this what you want @Albed? jsfiddle.net/qr853ehb

Comment: @William oh sry man I've just found what I need below and didn't turn back here but thanks alot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
triggers=document.getElementsByClassName('trigger');
for (let i=0;i< triggers.length;i++){
    triggers[i].addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
}
```

This snippet adds Event listener to all '.trigger' classed tags.